# regex: include the day optional in a variable date-format

Tags: regex

I have the following inputs

```
8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA_26-September-10_Item1

8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA_26-Sept-10_Item1

8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA_2-May-10_Item1

8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA-26-May-10_Item1

599_Evening_Ano-Jula-Saga_11_Jul-09_Item1

553_Sing-and-Other-Clips_Feb-09
```

And the following expression:

```
/.*(?:-|_)(\d{1,2}|)(?:-|_)(?i)([a-zA-Z]{3,4}|january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september)|october|november|december)(?-i)-(\d\d).*/
```

But I am unable to get the last result, which should be Feb-09 only. Does anybody have an idea how I can make the date optional?

Also I am quite new to regex. If someone has a suggestion for improving the regex, feel free.

[Click here for the demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX3mX2/2)

Comment: If you could please lay down the matching criteria then I can think on improving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
(?i)(?:-|_)(?:(\d{1,2})(?:-|_))?([a-z]{3,4}|january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)-(\d{2})
```

Basically I modified these points:

- Add a new optional non-matching group and enclose the first matching group in there
- make the entire pattern case-insensitive instead of just parts of it (which does not make much sense here)

---

**Edit:**

Here is an example of the above in PHP:

```php
$input = array();
$input[] = "8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA_26-September-10_Item1";
$input[] = "8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA_26-Sept-10_Item1";
$input[] = "8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA_2-May-10_Item1";
$input[] = "8_Evening-2010_Day4-UpTempo-NA-26-May-10_Item1";
$input[] = "599_Evening_Ano-Jula-Saga_11_Jul-09_Item1";
$input[] = "553_Sing-and-Other-Clips_Feb-09";

$pattern = "/(?i)(?:-|_)(?:(\d{1,2})(?:-|_))?([a-z]{3,4}|january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)-(\d{2})/";

foreach ($input as $string) {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
        print_r($matches);
}
```

As per the documentation of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) the first element (`[0]`) of `$matches` will contain the entire match. And the following three elements will represent the individual matching groups. `$matches[1]` will not be set for the last example since there is no day available.

Comment: Thanks this worked to some extend. How do I return only the regex match and not the entire input?

Comment: There are 3 matcher groups in the pattern (which you already used in your regex101 example). You should be able to access them directly (commonly via $1, $2, $3). If you tell me the language you are using I may be able to provide a code sample.

Comment: I am using php. On the demo page, and in my script, the substitution shows me the whole string, instead of the dates only. thanks.